# Login with FOSUser and Angular.js after auto-logout

Tags: angularjs, symfony, fosuserbundle

guys. I'm using FOSUser bundle and angular.js 1.5.0, angular-route 1.5.0 in my Symfony2.8 project. And I get some problem here. Well, when fosuser bundle make auto-logout, the login form are shown, that's ok.
And, my query string looks like that with angular-route:

```
www.site.com/#/some-page
```

So, fosuser make redirect to `/some-page`, but not to `/#/some-page`, when the form was filled.
By the way, everything works perfect for simple login, when you just opened site. Any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: I recommend you to remove the # from your angularjs app: https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520759/modify-symfony-redirect-path-after-re-login), the trick is to rewrite the symfony standard component `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler`