# Modify symfony redirect path after re-login

Tags: symfony, redirect

I have viewed a lot of similar questions but haven't found the answer.
Well, when the session expired, user will be redirected to the login page.
Then, user insert login/password and symfony redirects him to the previous page, like `/page`.
I want redirect user to `#/page`, so I need add `/#` string to referer path. How can I do that?
I'm using `FOSUserBundle`, but looks like that is what the symfony do.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure out the solution. We need to extend the Symfony security component `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, to be more specific - the `determineTargetUrl` method.

This piece of code is responsible for the url, after session ends

```
if (null !== $this->providerKey && $targetUrl = $request->getSession()->get('_security.'.$this->providerKey.'.target_path')) {
            $request->getSession()->remove('_security.'.$this->providerKey.'.target_path');

           return $targetUrl;
        }
```

So, let's extend this class and modify the `$targetUrl` value.

Firstable, create the handler, I have added the `AuthenticationHandler.php`
 in the `Vendor/YourBundle/Handle` directory

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\YourBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\ParameterBagUtils;

class AuthenticationHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    protected function determineTargetUrl(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->options['always_use_default_target_path']) {
            return $this->options['default_target_path'];
        }

        if ($targetUrl = ParameterBagUtils::getRequestParameterValue($request, $this->options['target_path_parameter'])) {
            return $targetUrl;
        }

        if (null !== $this->providerKey && $targetUrl = $request->getSession()->get('_security.'.$this->providerKey.'.target_path')) {
            $request->getSession()->remove('_security.'.$this->providerKey.'.target_path');

            $arr = explode('//', $targetUrl);
            $arr[1] = explode('/', $arr[1]);
            $arr[1][0] .= "/#";
            $arr[1] = implode('/', $arr[1]);
            $arr = implode('//', $arr);

            return $arr;
        }

        if ($this->options['use_referer'] && ($targetUrl = $request->headers->get('Referer')) && $targetUrl !== $this->httpUtils->generateUri($request, $this->options['login_path'])) {
            return $targetUrl;
        }

        return $this->options['default_target_path'];
    }
}
```

Register the service:

```
#services.yml

services:
    authentication_handler:
        class: Vendor\YourBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
        arguments:  ["@security.http_utils", {}]
        tags:
            - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

Define the handler:

```
#security.yml

     form_login:
         success_handler: authentication_handler
```

Enjoy!